# Add ToolMenuStripItem to MenuStrip at specific item?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, menustrip

I am using WinForms, i have tried TreeView and it almost have similar structure to the MenuStrip, only one thing i can't figure out is how to insert a ToolStripMenuItem as a sub item. Is there anyway maybe like:

```
//There is no Items.Add() after you find the toolstripitem array
MenuStrip.Items.Find("key").Items.Add().
//Same thing
ToolStripMenuItem.Items.Find("key").Items.Add().
```

I have tried almost everything and there is nothing like that at all, maybe someone could help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code.

```
        var item = menuStrip1.Items["toolStripMenuItem1"];

        ToolStripMenuItem newItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("my new item");
        var index = menuStrip1.Items.IndexOf(item);
        menuStrip1.Items.Insert(index + 1, newItem);
```

Edit: Updated with new code.

Edit2: This code will add the new menu item inside as dropdown item.

```
        ToolStripMenuItem item = (ToolStripMenuItem)menuStrip1.Items["toolStripMenuItem1"];

        ToolStripMenuItem newItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("my new item");
        item.DropDownItems.Add(newItem);
```

Comment: All my ToolStripMenuItem returns MergeIndex value -1, Why ?

Comment: did you try this code, it's not doing anything form me, it's just adding another item  not inside but next to it.

Comment: Yes, this code should add it item next to it. If you want to add items inside it, see the Edited code.

Comment: Seems all it took was just to parse the ToolStripItem to ToolStripMenuItem. Thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for.